# How to create a 100% stacked column chart if I have total

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts, powerpivot

I'm trying to create a 100% stacked column chart using Excel 2013 Pivot Table to show what % of Column A is of a Total Column B.

However the 100% stack column chart doesn't seem to work if I have a Total Column, only columns that sum to a total.

If I had a calculated "remainder" column, I could get this to work but this feature is disabled since the pivot table is made on relation of two tables.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this issue? I've attached a sample of what I have vs what I want to achieve with Power Pivot
[image]

Comment: You can try to use a calculated field in your pivot table to calculate the "remainder". See [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Calculate-values-in-a-PivotTable-report-697406b6-ee20-4a39-acea-8128b5e904b8).

Comment: The reason I can't add a calculated field is the table is joined to another table. The join is necessary to get the Total Column in the pivot table but I believe once you add a relationship Excel disables calculated fields.